Calculating the index of a sublattice created by appending a rational combination
Let $N = \mathbb{Z}^k$ be a lattice of rank $k$ and suppose $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ are vectors in $N$ which generate a sublattice of rank $k$ and index $n$. Suppose $v = \sum_i t_i v_i$ is a linear combination with $t_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $0 \leq t_i < 1$ such that $v \in N$. In Fulton's Introduction to Toric Varieties, there is claim that if $t_i$ is nonzero, then the sublattice generated by $v_1, \ldots, \widehat{v_i}, \ldots, v_k, v$ has index $t_i n$ in $N$. Why is this true? I'm not even sure why $t_i n$ has to be an integer.

There might be a less brutal way of doing it, but you could fix a basis $e=(e_1,...,e_k)$ of $N$, then express the $v_i$ in that basis. Then, expressing $v$ in this basis, you will see that $t_i$ cannot have a denominator greater than $n$ (otherwise you would end up with an element of $N$ with noninteger coefficients in the basis $e$). I'm convinced that making everything explicit like that will yield the result on the index, but it's not so pretty, and I myself don't want to do it.

Okay, I figured it out. The way to do it without any work is just to note that if $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ generate a sublattice of rank $k$, then the index is given by the determinant of the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}  & & \\ v_1 & \cdots & v_k \\ & & \end{pmatrix}$$ by standard linear algebra in $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, if we replace $v_i$ by $\sum t_i v_i$, the linear independence of the $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ tells us that the determinant of the resulting matrix is necessarily $t_i n$, and we get that it's an integer "for free."
